# How can I refresh Google Image Search cache?

Tags: caching, google-search

Google's image search caches the thumbnails of their images results. In one case, I've updated the image that Google is linking to but they continue to show the previous version as the thumbnail. Interestingly, if I click on the image or hover over it the new one is displayed. Is there a way to get Google to refresh this cached image or do I have to just wait it out?

Answer (score 3):

If you have set up Google search console on your website you can do followings to speed up updating cache content:

1. request removing of outdated content [here](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/removals?pli=1). In your case you should paste the url of image.
2. In **sitemap** section of search console, submit a sitemap which contains that specific URL.
3. in **URL INSPECTION** use REQUEST INDEXING to queue the inspection of that URL.

Note: none of the above guarantee the fast update of cached content. In all cases you have to wait for Google response.